# how to check, if there are still rows left from fetch_assoc loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I loop trough the rows with this code:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //...
}
```

But how is it possible before the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to check if there will be a next record, or not? I mean, like: `$result->hasNext()`

Comment: Simple. Use `$cnt = $result->num_rows;` before the loop. Next do `$cnt--;` inside your loop and `$cnt` will always contain the number of rows left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the total number of returned rows using $mysqli->num_rows, then compare it to a counter in your loop that you increment with each loop iteration.

```
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
$loop_ct = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(++$loop_ct < $row_cnt) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. But decrementing the row_cnt is a bit smarter way I think

Answer (score 4):

I prefer working efficiently and don't write extra code if it isn't needed. The following will work just fine:

```
$cnt = $result->num_rows;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    //....
    $cnt--;
    if($cnt == x){ //Where x is the number you want
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a while loop until you don't have any rows left, so the question is do you really need a test or do you just run the code you want at the end of your loop? If you need to test inside whether there will be a next row, you could do this:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
while (1) {
   ...
   if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      // No next row
      break;
   }
}
```

Which is pretty similar to what you're doing now.

Comment: but using fetch assoc it iterates to the next row, which I would like to avoid. I just like to check, if there are rows left

Comment: Maybe give us a little more insight into what your goal is so maybe I can give a better suggestion.

Comment: @IterAtor I bet there's a better approach if you told us what you are trying to achieve,

Answer (score 2):

Consider the code you posted

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  //...

}
```

It is already doing that. [check out the docs for mysqli_result::fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), the while loop will break if `$result->fetch_assoc()` returns NULL. You don't need to manually check anything.

Comment: I know. But I would like to check it anyway, before getting the next row

Answer (score 2):

Either you can go with @McWayWeb or you can try this function mysqli_next_result().

Read it's manual here:- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php